# Range(String) Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make this code running:

```
Dim myrange As String

For i = LBound(lOffsets) To UBound(lOffsets)
    myrange = "R" & CStr(2 * i + 4) & ":S" & CStr(2 * i + 5)
    Set rangeT = Worksheets("ChartBuilder").Range(myrange)

    Charts("overview").SeriesCollection.Add _
     Source:=rangeT
Next i
```

But I always get: Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range. It seams that Range() object doesn't want to accept myrange String as an input. The code works perfectly though if I use Range("R4:S5") for example ...

Comment: Are you sure that the sheet name `"ChartBuilder"` is spelled correctly and that the active workbook contains that sheet.

Comment: 100% Sure, it works when I use Range("R4:S5") for example

Comment: Why do you use `CStr()`? It doesn't seem to me like this would cause it to not work, but it also isn't necessary. Also, as @ScottCraner alludes to, you should qualify your workbook.

Comment: feels like few important parts of the code are missing like the declaration of `i`, `lOffsets` and `rangeT`. I recommend Record Macro of adding few of the ranges and check the generated code.

Comment: Is `lOffsets` actually a 1D array?  As if it's picked up from the workbook it'll be a 2D array and your `For` loop will be initialised wrong...

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim myrange As String


For i = LBound(lOffsets) To UBound(lOffsets)
    myrange = "R" & CStr(2 * i + 4) & ":R" & CStr(2 * i + 5) & "," & "S" & CStr(2 * i + 4) & ":S" & CStr(2 * i + 5)
    Set rangeT = Worksheets("ChartBuilder").Range(myrange)

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("overview").Chart.SeriesCollection.Add _
     Source:=rangeT
Next i
```

it works like this.